Get PayPal access token using OAuth
I'm going integrate PayPal OAuth and get customer's access token.
This is my html code.
<a id="setupPaypal" class="btn btn-primary" href="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/signin/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=[MyClientID]&scope=openid&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:54458/merchandise">Setup Paypal</a>

This is my redirect_uri handler code in asp.net c#.
var code = context.Request["code"].Trim();

try
{
    string clientId = "My PayPal Client ID";
    string secret = "My PayPal Client Secret";

    var authToken = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{clientId}:{secret}"));

    string paypalMode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Paypal_Mode"];
    var url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";

    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authToken);

    var requestBody = new StringContent($"grant_type=client_credentials&code={code}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, requestBody);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PayPalGetTokenResponse>(jsonResponse);
    }
    else
    {
        var errorResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(errorResponse);
        return default;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    return default;
}


public class PayPalGetTokenResponse
{
    public string scope { get; set; }
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string token_type { get; set; }
    public int expires_in { get; set; }
    public string nonce { get; set; }
}

This code returns access_token.
But when I use this access token it shows error message.
private async Task<string> CreateProductAsync(string paypalAccessToken)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/catalogs/products");
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", paypalAccessToken);

    var jsonBody = new
    {
        name = "Donation Product",
        description = "Custom donation subscription product",
        type = "SERVICE",
    };

    request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonBody), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseContent);
        return result.id; // Return the product ID
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Error creating product: " + responseContent);
    }
}

{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Access Token not found in cache"}
I'm trying to create donation product in customer's account using PayPal access token.
I have tried to integrate PayPal OAuth to get customer's access token.
And I'm going to create a product to customer's account using customer's access token.
But it shows error message.

See if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67073819/storage-of-microsoft-oauth2-access-token-and-refresh-token

That is not how to use a Log in with PayPal authorization code, which is the authorize flow your HTML code invokes.
See the documentation, grant_type should be authorization_code
The access_token you get will only be useful to get profile details. It is not an access_token (grant_type=client_credentials) for API operations.
To do API operations you will need to either prompt for the an app client_id and secret (copied from their developer.paypal.com dashboard) or look at being a PayPal partner with the multiparty onboard sellers API which is limited in what it can do; creating a donation subscription product may not be one of the things.

Preston PHX.
I can't be provided customer's client id and secret.
Because it is complicated for customers.
So I want to use PayPal OAuth to get access token and use it for donation payment.
Thanks for your answer.
